# Is there a way to run a for loop parallely inside mapPartitions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have three dataframes,

df1 = 100,000 rows, 300 columns and df2 = 100,000 rows, 300 columns and df3 = 100,000 rows, 300 columns

I join these dataframes on two values and then perform a mapPartitions, however, it is too slow. I have tried the following options,

**Cluster Config - Worker/Driver - 8 Cores and 32 GB RAM with 5 Worker Nodes.**

**Option 1: (20 mins to execute) **

```
df1 = df1.select("PrimaryId1","SecondaryId2", "FilePath1")
df2 = df2.select("PrimaryId1","SecondaryId2", "SecondaryId3", "FilePath2")
df3 = df3.select("PrimaryId1","SecondaryId3", "FilePath3")
df1_df2 = df1.join(df2, ["PrimaryId1","SecondaryId2"])
df1_df2_df3 = df1_df2.join(df3, ["PrimaryId1","SecondaryId3"])
rdd_ = df1_df2_df3.rdd.mapPartitions(custom_func)
mappedDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_, schema)
```

The **custom_func** just reads the data from the filepaths from dbfs and extracts some information and returns the RDD

The Problem is in the custom_func, due to the inner for loop in this function, it takes a lot of time to compute almost 2 hours to run through 15000 files which in my opinion is inefficient use of Spark

```
def custom_func(rdd):
  from pckg.xyz import getValuesAfterCalculations
  total_list = []
  for row in rdd:
    dict_ = getDictFromFile()
    for val in dict_.values():
      list_ = getValuesAfterCalculations(fileName, val)
      total_list .append(list_)
  return total_list
```

The getValuesAfterCalculations function performs a number of calculations on some matrices and this functiontakes a lot of time. Is there some way I could parallelize the for val in dict_values() for loop? Like multi-thread it inside the mapPArtitions()?

Comment: Can you share the code of `custom_func`? In the book `Spark: The Definitive Guide` from  Matei Zaharia, describes `rdd` when working with python, it needs to serialize and deserialize. Probably this is one reason for being too slow

Comment: @Kafels Yes I did run the joins separately and the problem doesnt seem to be there. It seems to be in the custom_func.

Comment: Update your question and add `custom_func` code

Comment: @Kafels Just did

Comment: Well, it doesn't helped. I suggest you to share a data sample, a reproducible code and desired output, depending what you need, your `custom_func` could be rewritten in another manner